# Nested Structure With Class. Scope Error

Tags: c++, class, nested, structure

I'm here trying to implement **Linked Lists** using **C++**.
In the following program i'm trying to implement **Linear Search** using **Linked Lists**. But the `SearchLL` function in the following code, which is a friend function, is giving this error:

> `error: head was not declared in this scope`

What is wrong here?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int info;
    node* link;
};
class LinkedList
{
private:
    node* head;
    node* ptr;
public:
LinkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
int addnode(int x)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = new node;
        ptr = head;
        ptr->info = x;
        ptr->link = NULL;

    }
    else
    {
        node* n = new node;
        ptr->link = n;
        ptr = n;
        ptr->info = x;
        ptr->link = NULL;
    }
    return 1;
}
friend void searchLL(int); 
};
void searchLL(int item)
{
    node* temp = head;
    node* loc = NULL;
    while(temp->link!=NULL || item!=temp->info)
        temp = temp->link;

    if(temp->info == item);
        cout<<endl<<loc;

    return;
}
int main()
{
    LinkedList l1;
    l1.addnode(10);
    l1.addnode(20);
    searchLL(20);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
node* temp = head;
```

The `SearchLL()` function is referring here to an object called `head`. There's no such object defined in the shown code.

There is a class member called `head`, in the `LinkedList` class that `SearchLL()` is a friend of. However, `head` is a class member, and you need an instance of a class to access it.

It appears that `SearchLL()` is written as if it was a class method. It is not. It is a `friend` function. A `friend` function is not a class method, it does not have a `this`. It's just a function that, given an instance of a class, will have access to the otherwise non-public members and methods of its `friend` class, that's all. You still need to explicitly pass a pointer, or a reference, to the class instance, to the friend function.